# unable to completely protect excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I am trying to make an access request form, where the requester can choose the access needed and submit via email for approval. In my form, I have used Text Box (ActiveX Control) for the fields where the requester can enter details manually – like their name. for some fields, like the department which they belong to, I have used Combo Box (ActiveX Control) for dropdown lists and Check Box (ActiveX Control) for choosing the access / rights they are requesting for.

[image: Text Fields and Dropdown]

[image: check boxes]

Once they have entered all the details and when they click on send button, all the fields should get locked and no more edits should be possible. I have added the below macro for protecting the sheet, and once clicked, it is showing protected, but still I am able to make changes in text boxes, checkbox and drop downs.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next ws
```

I've tried

```vb
Sub DisableBxs() 
    TADeptCombBx1.Enabled = False 
    TADeptCombBx2.Enabled = False 
    CheckBox1.Enabled = False 
    CheckBox10.Enabled = False 
    FirstNameTxtBx.Enabled = False 
    MiddleNameTxtBx.Enabled = False 
    FirstNameTxtBx.Enabled = False 
    MiddleNameTxtBx.Enabled = False 
    FirstNameTxtBx.Enabled = False 
    MiddleNameTxtBx.Enabled = False 
End Sub
```

I've have got 170 text boxes, checkboxes and combo boxes all together in the sheet. When executing the code, it is giving me the error 'object not found' when debugged

Comment: You'll need to also turn off the [`Enabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.enabled) property of all the controls on your sheet

Comment: Hello Chris, i have tried that as well. Textbox.enabled = False. But no luck

Comment: I've used `.Enabled = False` many times.  Show us how you've tried it, we may be able to fix that for you

Comment: Sub DisableBxs()
TADeptCombBx1.Enabled = False
TADeptCombBx2.Enabled = False

CheckBox1.Enabled = False
CheckBox10.Enabled = False
FirstNameTxtBx.Enabled = False
MiddleNameTxtBx.Enabled = False

FirstNameTxtBx.Enabled = False
MiddleNameTxtBx.Enabled = False
FirstNameTxtBx.Enabled = False
MiddleNameTxtBx.Enabled = False

End Sub

Comment: i have got 170 text boxes, checkboxes and combo boxes all together in the sheet.. when executing the code, it is giving me the error 'object not found' when debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent entry into the objects, you need to turn off their `Enabled` propertry.

To access ActiveX objects placed on a sheet you need to use the Worksheet `OLEObjects` collection.

Something like

```vb
Sub ProtectAndDisableControls()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ctrl As Object
    
    ' to exclude by control Name
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each ctrl In ws.OLEObjects
            If Not LCase$(ctrl.Name) Like "approve*" _
              And Not LCase$(ctrl.Name) Like "reject*" Then
                ctrl.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next ctrl
    Next ws

    ' optional,  to exclude specific control type(s)
'    For Each ws In Worksheets
'        For Each ctrl In ws.OLEObjects
'            If Not TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
'                ctrl.Enabled = False
'            End If
'        Next ctrl
'    Next ws
        
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot, Chris. this worked. but I have got 6 other buttons, which will be used by the approver. when the above code is used, those buttons are also getting disabled. is there any way to exclude those buttons?

Comment: @pranav of course there is.  Condition the loop to exclude them.  There are many possible ways to do that. Are they of a sheet with other controls, or on a seperate sheet? Are they the only buttons in the workbook? Do they have a Name pattern you can use to identify them?

Comment: they are in the same sheet. I have named it as approve01, approve02, reject01, reject02, etc.

Comment: Updated answer.  Alos, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris. the optional method did work!! and one last question, is it possible to avoid the greyout of text once it is disabled?

Comment: @pranav _is it possible to avoid the greyout of text once it is disabled_ - no, it's not.  That how disabled controls display

Comment: in this case, instead of making it disabled is there any way to make it read-only? here, my problem is, once disabled all the fields are grayed-out and it's difficult to read the contents. :). hope you could help me . thanks in advance.